# Boolean prime ideal theorem and the axiom of choice

Tags: reference-request, logic, examples-counterexamples, axiom-of-choice

The [Boolean prime ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem) is strictly stronger than ZF, and strictly weaker than ZFC. I'm looking for nice examples (like the existence of non-measurable set) that request at least that theorem (ZF+BPI), but weaker than AC (ZFC).

The context is that I'm trying to gain some intuition, but most literature I could get access to is very technical and being lost in the details I can't see the big picture. Any help (like examples or your intuition behind it) or references that provide examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Boolean Prime Ideal theorem has a lot of useful equivalents. Two important ones are:

1. The completeness theorem for first-order logic.
2. The compactness theorem for first-order logic.

What you wrote in your question, however, is not fully accurate. The existence of a non-measurable subset does not require "*at least*" the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem. It is in fact much much weaker than that; and is implied by weaker principles (e.g. Hahn-Banach theorem) as well very different principles (e.g. $\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}+\sf DC$ implies the existence of a non-measurable set).

If you are looking for consequences of $\sf BPI$ which are unprovable from $\sf ZF$ itself then there are plenty. Here are a few:

1. Every set can be linearly ordered.
2. Every infinite set has a non-trivial ultrafilter.
3. If $V$ is a vector space, and $V$ has a basis $B$ then every basis of $V$ has the same cardinality as $B$.
4. Marshall Hall's marriage theorem.
5. Every partial order can be extended to a linear order.
6. Hahn-Banach theorem.
7. Every field has an algebraic closure, which is unique up to isomorphism.
8. Every family of finite non-empty sets admits a choice function.

And many many more.

Some of these examples you can find in the surprisingly not-very-technical book by Herrlich, **The Axiom of Choice**.

If you are looking for principles which are unprovable from $\sf BPI$, but true in $\sf ZFC$, then there are plenty of these as well:

1. The axiom of countable choice.
2. Every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite.
3. More generally, $\sf DC_\kappa$, for any $\kappa$.
4. The statement "For every infinite cardinal $\frak a$, $\frak a+a=a$".

And many many others.

Comment: In the second paragraph I think you meant $\aleph_1<2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @Camilo: No. I didn't. I meant $\leq$.

Comment: @Camilo: If $2^{\aleph_0}$ is an $\aleph$-number then it's extremely easy to prove the existence of non-measurable sets (e.g. Vitali sets, Bernstein sets, Hamel bases and their consequences, ultrafilters on $\omega$, and so on).

Comment: Even more examples I was looking for ;-) Indeed, I was searching for consequences of $\mathsf{BPI}$ which are unprovable in $\mathsf{ZF}$. Could you possibly add an example that is weaker than $ZFC$, but unprovable in $\mathsf{BPI}$ (if such is known)?

Comment: @dtldarek: Of course. I've added a few.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful ;-)

Answer (score 6):

An example from topology: $\mathsf{BPI}$ is equivalent to the Tikhonov product theorem for compact **Hausdorff** spaces, while $\mathsf{AC}$ is equivalent to the full Tikhonov product theorem.

Comment: Well, that's exactly a kind of example I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @dtldarek: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

There is a book, *Equivalents of the Axiom of Choice* (two volumes) by Rubin and Rubin that has an exhaustive catalog of principles equivalent to AC.  The book *Consequences of the Axiom of Choice* by Howard and Rubin has many more principles that are weaker than AC. There is also a book *The Axiom of Choice* by Jech that discuses the prime ideal theorem.

Comment: You mean [this](http://books.google.pl/books?id=pToedF7dZ7sC) (and the second volume [here](http://books.google.pl/books?id=LSsbBU9FesQC)) and [this](http://books.google.pl/books?id=1qEgAQAAMAAJ)?

Comment: @dtldarek: You may also be interested in Herrlich's **The Axiom of Choice** book which contains a lot of nice equivalence of $\sf BPI$.

Answer (score -1):

A great reference for Consequences of the Axiom of Choice and their relations to each other is the book by Paul Howard and Jean Rubin, Consequences of the Axiom of Choice.