# Fragment of ZFC to prove first-order completeness theorem

Tags: first-order-logic

If I am not mistaken PRA or an even weaker theory suffices to develop the syntactics of first-order logic (at least for finite or countable languages). 
To develop the semantics of first-order logic sets are assumed. I am wondering what fragment of ZFC is necessary to (1) develop the semantics of first-order logic, (2) prove the completeness theorem of first-order logic.

Comment: Is "PRA" one of those systems used in "reverse mathematics"?

Comment: See answer to [questions-about-mathematical-content-of-completeness-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631750/some-questions-about-mathematical-content-of-g%c3%b6dels-completeness-theorem)

Comment: @Michael $\mathsf{PRA}$ is primitive recursive arithmetic, which can be regarded as a weak fragment of first-order Peano Arithmetic. Reverse mathematics, as typically understood, on the other hand, is concerned with second-order systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very little.

First of all, an important fragment of the completeness theorem doesn't even need "big" sets at all. Consider the "countable completeness theorem":

> $(*)$ If $T$ is a consistent theory in a countable language, then $T$ has a countable model.

This can be appropriately expressed in the language of second-order$^*$ arithmetic, and in fact is quite weak: over the base theory RCA$_0$, which corresponds roughly to "computable mathematics," the principle $(*)$ is equivalent to **weak Konig's lemma** (wkl) - the statement that every infinite binary tree has an infinite path. One direction - proving $(*)$ from RCA$_0$ + wkl *(this latter system is called "WKL$_0$" - note that "WKL" denotes a stronger theory, hence my usage of "wkl" above)* because over RCA$_0$ the principle wkl lets us prove (the appropriate form of) Lindenbaum's lemma, and modulo that the usual Henkinization proof is entirely effective.

---

Now what about the more general completeness theorem?

Well,there's an interesting split: we have on the one hand the "well-ordered completeness theorem"

> $(**)$ If $T$ is a consistent theory in a well-orderable language, then $T$ has a well-orderable model,

and the "full" completeness theorem

> $(***)$ If $T$ is a consistent theory, then $T$ has a model.

The principle $(***)$ is *not provable in ZF* - it requires a small amount of choice (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519424/boolean-prime-ideal-theorem-and-the-axiom-of-choice)). The former principle, however, is provable in ZF; looking at the usual Henkinization argument, we see that it consists of:

- Pass from $T$ to a complete consistent theory $\hat{T}$ (Lindenbaum's lemma).
- Pass from $\hat{T}$ to a larger complete consistent theory $T^+$ in an expanded language, with the witness property (Henkinization).
- Argue that the term model of $T^+$ is in fact a model of $T^+$, and hence its reduct to our original language is a model of $T$.

It's not hard to check that this goes through in the theory [KP + Inf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory) (the axiom of infinity needed to form sets of finite sequences). This is not optimal, but it's a good first approximation. Meanwhile, by the same reasoning KP + Inf + the well-ordering theorem proves $(***)$.

Incidentally, the development of logic inside KP + Inf and related weak fragments of ZFC has been intensely studied - [Barwise has an excellent book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235418470) which treats these issues (among others). Of particular interest I think is the relationship between weak fragments of ZFC and logics *beyond* first-order logic, specifically (fragments of) infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\omega}$ - see for example the **Barwise compactness theorem**.

---

A minor obnoxiousness: although it's called "second-*order* arithmetic," everything here is *first*-order in the sense of the underlying logic. In my opinion, "second-order arithmetic" should really be called "*two-sorted* arithmetic" *(I'd also be happier with "analysis," which has been used this way historically, but not quite as happy since that has connotations of its own)* but unfortunately the name has stuck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the trouble to answer my question in so much detail! 
How can I accept your answer?

Comment: Found where to click to accept an answer.