# Ultrafilter proof of the infinite Ramsey Theorem

Tags: set-theory, filters, ramsey-theory

The Infinite Ramsey Theorem ($\mathsf{RT}$) is the statement

> For any $r,p\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ and any infinite set $A$, any $r$-coloring $c$ of $[A]^{p}$ has an infinite homogeneous subset.

Where $[r] = \{1,\ldots r\}$, and $[A]^{p}$ is the set of $p$-element subsets of $A$. A function $c:[A]^{p}\rightarrow [r]$ is called an $r$-coloring of $[A]^{p}$, and a subset $H\subseteq A$ is homogeneous for $c$ if $c$ is constant on ${[H]^{p}}$.

I am trying to prove $\mathsf{RT}$ by induction on $p$, but I am stuck in the general induction step. Here is what I have so far:

The case $p=1$, $r\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ is simply the infinite pigeonhole principle and it is clear.

The case $p=2$, $r\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ (which I thought solving would help me understand how to use an ultrafilter in the general induction step) goes as follows: Apply the [Ultrafilter Theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ultrafilter+theorem) to extend the non-principal filter defined by the collection of all cofinite subsets of $A$ to a non-principal ultrafilter $U$ on $A$.

For each $a\in A$ and each color $i\in[r]$, let $A_{i}^{a} = \{b\in A-\{a\}:c(\{a,b\})=i\}$. Then, for each $a\in A$ we have a partition $\{A_{1}^{a},\ldots,A_{r}^{a},\{a\}\}$ of $A$, and since $U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter we must have exactly one of the $A_{i}^{a}\in U$. For each $a\in A$, let $i_{a}$ denote the unique color such that $A_{i_{a}}^{a}\in U$. The function $f:a\mapsto i_{a}$ is an $r$-coloring of $[A]^{1}$, and therefore there is an infinite homogeneous subset $X\in U$ for $f$. Let $k=f(X)$ (another way of seeing this is that sets $\{a\in A:i_{a}=1\},\ldots,\{a\in A:i_{a}=r\}$ form a partition of $A$. Therefore, exactly one of them is in $U$ since $U$ is an ultrafilter. Let $k$ denote the unique color such that $X = \{a\in A: i_{a} = k\}\in U$).

This set $X$ may already be homogeneous for $c$? In any case, since it is infinite we can pick $a_{0}\in X$. Let $X_{1}=X\cap A_{k}^{a_{0}}$. Since $U$ is a filter, $X_{1}\in U$ and is infinite, and there is $a_{1}\in X_{1}$. Note that $a_{0}$ and $a_{1}$ are distinct. Continue this process to obtain $a_{i}\in X_{i}=X\cap\bigcap_{j<i}A_{k}^{a_{i}}$, where $X_{i}\in U$ and is infinite.

We claim that the set $H=\{a_{i}:i\geq 0\}$ is homogeneous for $c$. Indeed, for all $i<j$ it is clear that $a_{j}\in A_{k}^{a_{i}}$. Therefore, $c(\{a_{i},a_{j}\})=k$, as desired.

Question 1: Have I made any mistakes so far?

Now, let $p\geq 2$ and the result to hold for all $r\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ and for $p$. Let $c:[A]^{p+1}\to[r]$ be an $r$-coloring of $[A]^{p+1}$. Let $U$ be the same non-principal ultrafilter on $A$.

Question 2: How do I proceed?

---

Update

Here is an idea: For each $a\in A$ and each color $i\in[r]$, let $A_{i}^{a} = \{B\in [A-\{a\}]^{p}:c(B\cup\{a\})=i\}$. Then, for each $a\in A$ the sets $\{A_{1}^{a},\ldots,A_{r}^{a}\}$ partition $[A-\{a\}]^{p}$, which defines an $r$-coloring $c_{a}$ of $[A-\{a\}]^{p}$. Therefore, by the induction hypothesis, for each $a\in A$ there is a homogeneous subset $H_{a}\subseteq A-\{a\}$ for $c_{a}$. Since $U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter, for each $a\in A$ we have $H_{a}\in U$ is infinite. For each $a\in A$, let $k_{a} = c_{a}([H_{a}]^{p})$. The set $\{k_{a}:a\in A\}$ is indexed by an infinite set $A$, but is is a subset of $[r]$. Therefore, by the infinite pigeonhole principle there is $k\in[r]$ such that $k=k_{a}$ for infinitely many $a\in A$. Let
$$H = \bigcup_{k_{a}=k}H_{a},$$
which is clearly in $U$ and is therefore infinite. We claim that $H$ is homogeneous for $c$. Indeed, let $H'\in[H]^{p+1}$. Pick any $a\in H'$. Then the set $H'-\{a\}\in [A-\{a\}]^{p}$, and $c_{a}(H'-\{a\}) = k$ hmm.. no there is something wrong here. This is not true necessarily...

A good hint would do :)

Comment: I'm unclear on why you're trying to use an ultrafilter. The usual inductive proof of the IRT looks pretty similar, but simpler IMO. What do you feel the ultrafilter buys you?

Comment: Both the Ultrafilter Theorem ($\mathsf{UT}$, which is $\mathsf{ZF}$-equivalent to the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem - $\mathsf{BPI}$) and $\mathsf{RT}$ are weak forms of the axiom of choice (certainly countable choice implies $\mathsf{RT}$, but you can use the much weaker form *every infinite set has a countable subset*). However, neither $\mathsf{UT}\not\Rightarrow\mathsf{RT}$ nor $\mathsf{RT}\not\Rightarrow\mathsf{UT}$ over $\mathsf{ZF}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4707020/30229)) I am trying to see how much choice we may need to make $\mathsf{UT}\Rightarrow\mathsf{RT}$ true.

Comment: Also, if we miniaturize $\mathsf{RT}$ as follows: $A=\mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathsf{RT}(p)$ be the statement -*For any $r\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$, any $r$-coloring $c$ of $[\mathbb{N}]^{p}$ as an infinite homogeneous subset*- We have in the context of reverse mathematics, that $\mathsf{ACA}_{0}$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{RT}(3)$ over $\mathsf{RCA}_{0}$. Therefore, to simply have a non-principal ultrafilter (which proves $\mathsf{RT}(3)$) implies $\mathsf{ACA}_{0}$ over $\mathsf{RCA}_{0}$. See [this](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2015-September/019166.html).

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After staring at the case $p=2$ long enough I think I have a solution which generalizes this case, and it does not need induction after all. Here it goes:

Let $p,r\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$, $p>1$, and let $c$ be an $r$-coloring of $[A]^{p}$. Let $U$ be the same non-principal ultrafilter on $A$ we used in the case $p=2$.

The idea is to use $U$ and $c$ in order to define for each $1\leq m\leq p$ an $r$-coloring $c_{m}$ of $[A]^{m}$. We do this recursively:

Let $c_{p}=c$. Next, for each $B\in[A]^{p-1}$ and each $i\in[r]$ define a set $A^{p-1}_{i}(B)=\{a\in A-B:c_{p}(B\cup\{a\}) = i\}$. Then, for each $B\in[A]^{p-1}$ we have a partition $\{A^{p-1}_{1}(B),\ldots,A^{p-1}_{r}(B), B\}$ of $A$. Since $U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter there must be exactly one $i_{B}\in[r]$ such that $A^{p-1}_{i_{B}}(B)\in U$, and we can define for each $B\in[A]^{p-1}$ $c_{p-1}(B)=i_{B}$.

In general, once the $r$-coloring $c_{m+1}$ of $[A]^{m+1}$ has been defined, we define for each $B\in[A]^{m}$ and each $i\in[r]$ the set $A_{i}^{m}(B)=\{a\in A-B:c_{m+1}(B\cup\{a\})=i\}$. The exact same argument using the ultrafilter $U$ yields for each $B\in[A]^{m}$ a unique $i_{B}\in[r]$ we use to define an $r$-coloring $c_{m}$ of $[A]^{m}$.

We continue this process until we have eventually defined an $r$-coloring $c_{1}$ of $A$, i.e. a partition $\{a\in A:c_{1}(1)=1\},\ldots,\{a\in A:c_{1}(a)=r\}$ of $A$. Our good friend the ultrafilter tells us that there is exactly one $k\in[r]$ such that the set $X=\{a\in A:c_{1}(a)=k\}\in U$. Note that $X$ is thus infinite.

Ok, now what? Well, we will use $X$ and the load of dribble above to construct a set $H$ with the property that

> for each $1\leq m\leq p$ and every $B\in[H]^{m}$, we have $c_{m}(B)=k$.

That will certainly show that $H$ is homogeneous for $c$!

We construct $H$ recursively. Since $X$ is infinite, pick $a_{0}\in X$ and let $H_{0}=\{a_{0}\}$. Next, let
$$X_{1} = X\cap A_{k}^{1}(\{a_{0}\})$$
Since $U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter and each set in the intersection is in $U$ then $X_{1}$ is also in $U$ and is thus infinite (note $a_{0}\not\in X_{1}$). Pick $a_{1}\in X_{1}$ and let $H_{1}=\{a_{0},a_{1}\}$.

We continue this process, and once $H_{n}=\{a_{0},\ldots a_{n}\}$ has been defined, the set $X_{n+1}$ will have the form
$$X_{n+1} = X\cap\left(\bigcap_{b\in H_{n}}A_{k}^{1}(\{b\})\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{B\in[H_{n}]^{2}}A_{k}^{2}(B)\right)\cap\cdots\cap\left(\bigcap_{B\in[H_{n}]^{p-1}}A_{k}^{p-1}(B)\right)$$

(Of course, if $n$ is less than $p$, the expression above is truncated, and after $n$ goes beyond $p$ we do not add additional big-parenthesis terms)

In any case, this intersection is finite and each term is in $U$, guaranteeing that $X_{n+1}\in U$ and is thus infinite. Pick $a_{n+1}\in X_{n+1}$.

Continue this process *ad infinitum* to add a distinct element at each step to our growing set of $a_{n}$'s and simply define $H=\cup_{n\ge 0}H_{n}=\{a_{n}:n\geq 0\}$. It is clear from the construction that $H$ has the desired property highlighted above, and is thus infinite homogeneous for $c$. And done! What a little industrious ultrafilter $U$ has been :)

A final though (see the comments to the question): Constructing $H$ assumes the infinite set $X$ has a countable subset, and the statement $(\mathsf{C})$ -*Every infinite set has a countable subset*- is a (weak) form of the axiom of choice. Therefore, if I have not made any mistakes, we have that $\mathsf{UT}+\mathsf{C}\Rightarrow\mathsf{RT}$ over $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: Very nice. I was starting to write an answer with essentially the same proof when you posted your answer. A comment on your final thought: Yes, you've shown that $\mathsf{UT}+\mathsf{C}\implies \mathsf{RT}$ over $\mathsf{ZF}$. But it's already true that $\mathsf{C}\implies \mathsf{RT}$ over $\mathsf{ZF}$! So the ultrafilter really isn't necessary here. In my opinion, the ultrafilter proof is valuable because (1) it gives an alternative approach which doesn't use induction on $p$, and (2) it suggests how ultrafilters can be useful in proving other Ramsey-style theorems (and indeed they are!).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you, I appreciate it. Oh, yes $\mathsf{C}\Rightarrow\mathsf{RT}$ via the standard proof of $\mathsf{RT}$ by induction on $p$. Not needing induction was certainly a welcome feature. I have a question: do you know of a proof of $\mathsf{RT}$ via propositional (or first-order) compactness?

Comment: No, I don't. There is a standard proof by compactness that the infinite Ramsey theorem implies the finite Ramsey theorem. But of course no choice is necessary to prove the finite Ramsey theorem.

Comment: @AlexKruckman By chance, I found a proof of the finite Ramsey Theorem using first-order compactness on 12.9. p.273 of *A Course in Model Theory: An Introduction to Contemporary Mathematical Logic*, by Bruno Poizat - Springer, 2000. Interesting.